# Java - Returning List based on condition

Tags: java, list, return

I have the following method `getTeams()` which returns list of teams `List<Team>` of a particular account (i.e., `this.teams`).
I want to return the teams which are active only (`find.where().eq("active",true)`)

I need the list of teams of the account which satisfy the condition (active teams), but I am unable to do it. I mean I was able to return either `this.teams` or teams which are active. So how will I be able to combine these? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

```
public List<Team> getTeams() {
    return Team.find.where().eq("active", true).findList();
    //return this.teams;
}
```

Comment: What is the condition to return the one or the other?

Comment: @kocko But I just received a notification saying that you have answered my question and that did work for me! But now I cannot see that answer?

Comment: And a vote down?! But why? Can I please know the reason?

Comment: I undeleted the answer. I deleted it because I thought there's a condition for returning one or the other list.

Comment: @kocko  Condition/Criteria is that, method should return the particular account's teams which are active! You have understood my question and you have provided the solution! But why did you delete it now?

Comment: Fair enough. Upvote/accept if you find it useful. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Java 8, you can do it with a single statement (assuming you have a `List<Team>` as `teams` and the `Team` type has a `.isActive()` method:

```
return this.teams.stream()
                 .filter(Team::isActive)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, if you're using some of the older versions of Java, you can do:

```
List<Team> result = new ArrayList<Team>();
for (Team team : this.teams) {
    if (team.isActive()) { 
        result.add(team);
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: I think mine is not java 8, but 2nd worked like a charm! This is actually a fine solution using for loop. I will keep this in mind. Thanks!